# xslt: converting characters to their hexadecimal Unicode representation

Tags: xslt

This is my input html (xhtml)

```
<SPAN style="font-family: wingdings"></SPAN>
```

I want to create an xml node like the following

```
<w:sym w:font="wingdings" w:char="F0D8"/>
```

How to get the character Unicode hexadecimal valude (F0D8) from the html: suggest a template for this.

Comment: Did I understand that correctly: You want to transform an HTML document to an XML document via XSLT? It works the other way around.

Comment: yes. How to read the character in html xia xslt..Is there any function

Comment: @musiKk: Why not? If it's XHTML you can still transform it

Comment: @Lukas: Then you should explicitly ask for XHTML. There are wolds between HTML and XHTML when it comes to processing. Assuming they are remotely the same is imho foolish.

Comment: @musiKk: I know. You're this guy: http://xkcd.com/386/ :-)

Comment: @Lukas: Yawn... you must be new here.

Comment: @musiKk: You're probably right

Answer (score 6):

I was doing exactly the same thing as [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482860/need-to-handle-special-characters/5483290#5483290) :) Anyway, here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn my xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:function name="my:int-to-hex" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="if ($in eq 0)
                then '0'
                else
                  concat(if ($in gt 16)
                         then my:int-to-hex($in idiv 16)
                         else '',
                         substring('0123456789ABCDEF',
                                   ($in mod 16) + 1, 1))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="//SPAN">
        <sym>
            <xsl:attribute name="char">
                <xsl:value-of select="my:int-to-hex(
                                        fn:string-to-codepoints(.))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </sym>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `int-to-hex` function is courtesy of [Yves Forkl](http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200902/msg00215.html). The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sym char="F0D8"/>
```

I don't know how to do this using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I tried this code, its showing ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'stringToCodepoints' is not a valid object reference.'

Comment: @vignesh: it works for me. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 2.0 you can get the numeric value of the character using the `string-to-codepoints()` function. You'll have to write a function to convert it to hex yourself, but that's not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is one error in @MarcoS's function: instead of `if ($in gt 16)` should be `if ($in ge 16)` (greater then or equal). Wrong hexadecimal values were generated for example for number 259.

The full function should looks like this:

```
<xsl:function name="my:int-to-hex" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence
        select="if ($in eq 0)
        then '0'
        else
        concat(if ($in ge 16)
        then my:int-to-hex($in idiv 16)
        else '',
        substring('0123456789ABCDEF',
        ($in mod 16) + 1, 1))"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

Comment: Actually, the smart thing to do is start by computing the quotient; then proceed with `if $q, f($q)`. The other test, `$in eq 0` is redundant as well.