# How can I decode XML hexadecimal entities into the corresponding character in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, svg, fonts, hex, xslt-1.0

### Context

I'm processing fonts file with [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and convert font to SVG files with the [`ttf2svg` command](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html). However the ouput given by Batik XML encode the initial –Chinese– glyph.

### Current XML

```
<glyph unicode="&#xf900;" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="…" />
```

### Target XML

```
<glyph unicode="豈" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="…"/>
```

### XSL template

```
<xsl:template match="svg:glyph" mode="from-block">    
  <xsl:copy-of select="."  disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

### Question

**How can I decode XML hexadecimal entities** into the corresponding character in **XSLT 1.0**?

Comment: Can you explain the nature of the requirement better?  Is some downstream process that claims to accept XML input but that cannot handle numeric character references?  Or is it just a cosmetic requirement:  you'd like your XML to use Unicode characters, not numeric references to them?  In either case, I'd write a simple identity transform and specify that the output encoding should be UTF-8.  (But if it were that simple, I guess you wouldn't have asked the question, since the solution is obvious.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen how would you speficy the UTF-8 output encoding?

Comment: With `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>`.  It's still not clear why you think you need to do anything at all here.  The output produced by Batik and the form you say you want contain exactly the same information and will be processed the same by any conforming XML parser.  Insisting on a particular encoding looks a bit like totemism.

Comment: I know the XML entities represent the character, but it's a lot easier for human to work with character instead of entities

Comment: True.  That's a good reason to work with an XML-aware editor able to display the characters in their expanded form.

Answer (score 0):

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

[Michael Kay's answer on xslt: converting characters to their hexadecimal Unicode representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482860/xslt-converting-characters-to-their-hexadecimal-unicode-representation) gave some hint to the solution of hex→char problem:

- [`fn:string-to-codepoints`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_string-to-codepoints.html):   Creates a sequence of Unicode code points **from a string** ;
- [`fn:codepoints-to-string`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_codepoints-to-string.html):   Creates a string **from a sequence of Unicode code points**.