# XSLT: Convert specific characters of a string individually to a string *including* their values in hex

Tags: xslt, rtf

I need some help, converting some 8-bit ASCII characters to a string containg their hexadezimal value. I want to convert german umlauts (äöüÄÖÜß) to their hexadecimal *RTF* representation. For example the character `ä` shall be converted to `\'E4`.

I know other solutions for conversions of characters, like [xslt: converting characters to their hexadecimal Unicode representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482860/xslt-converting-characters-to-their-hexadecimal-unicode-representation). But when I tried to use this in combination with `xsl:replace()`, only the `$` character is converted, not the result of the matching group `$0`.

So here is, what I have tried. Somewhere in the stylesheet I use this, to convert some chars of the string:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($rtfText, '[äöüßÄÖÜ]', at:char-to-unicode('$0'))"/>
```

`at:int-to-hex` is the functions, from the other question. I thought it would be a good idea to use it in another function:

```
   <xsl:function name="at:char-to-unicode" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="concat('\\''', at:int-to-hex(string-to-codepoints('$in')[1]))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="at:int-to-hex" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="if ($in eq 0)
            then '0'
            else
            concat(if ($in gt 16)
            then at:int-to-hex($in idiv 16)
            else '',
            substring('0123456789ABCDEF',
            ($in mod 16) + 1, 1))"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use? Do you need that escaping in all output so that in XSLT 2/3 a character map might suffice or only in some computations in your stylesheet?

Comment: As for `string-to-codepoints('$in')`, that should be `string-to-codepoints($in)` I guess.

Comment: Currently I use Saxon 9.8.0.12, the one which is included in <oXygen/> 21. I think I will use Saxon HE in the end product so XSLT 3 is fine. Regarding the `'$in'` you are right. I just tried too many variants, sorry. I think the main issue is, that `at:char-to-unicode('$0')` does not translate to `at:char-to-unicode('ä')` and `at:char-to-unicode($0)` (or `string-to-codepoints($0)[0])`) fails with `expected "<name>", found "<numeric-literal>"`. I need the escaping in all output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say you use XSLT 2 or 3 and want to replace the characters in the complete output document I think using a character map is the easiest approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="text" use-character-maps="rtf-hex"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="rtf-hex">
       <xsl:output-character character="ä" string="\'E4"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="ö" string="\'F6"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="ü" string="\'FC"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="Ä" string="\'C4"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="Ö" string="\'D6"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="Ü" string="\'DC"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="ß" string="\'DF"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpr/1 has an example.

In XSLT 3 you can also use character maps locally on a string thanks to the `serialize` functions and its second parameter where you can define the character map as an XPath 3.1 `map(xs:string, xs:string)` e.g.

```
serialize(., map { "method" : "text", "use-character-maps" : map{"Ä":"\C4","ä":"\E4","Ö":"\D6","ö":"\F6","Ü":"\DC","ü":"\FC","ß":"\DF"} })
```

to have the mapping applied so

```
<text xml:lang="de">Dies ist ein Test mit Umlauten: ä, ö, ü, ß, Ä, Ö, Ü.</text>
```

would be transformed by

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select='serialize(., map { "method" : "text", "use-character-maps" : map{"Ä":"\C4","ä":"\E4","Ö":"\D6","ö":"\F6","Ü":"\DC","ü":"\FC","ß":"\DF"} })'/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to

```
<text>Dies ist ein Test mit Umlauten: \E4, \F6, \FC, \DF, \C4, \D6, \DC.</text>
```

I realize that last example doesn't have the exact replacement you described but as I tried to generate the used map dynamically and run into a problem with Saxon to generate the right syntax to use the map inside of an XSLT attribute you will need to fix values like `map{"Ä":"\C4"` to `map{"Ä":"\&apos;C4"`.

As for matching based on a regular expression and replacing them, in XSLT 3.0 using the `analyze-string` function you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:int-to-hex" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="int" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence
         select="if ($int eq 0) 
                 then '0' 
                 else concat(
                          if ($int gt 16)
                          then mf:int-to-hex($int idiv 16) else '',
                          substring('0123456789ABCDEF', ($int mod 16) + 1, 1)
                      )"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="analyze-string(., '\p{IsLatin-1 Supplement}')/*/(if (. instance of element(fn:match)) then '\''' || mf:int-to-hex(string-to-codepoints(.)) else string())" separator=""/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6f

Comment: I did not knew the character-map, thanks a lot; it solved my specific problem. Maybe I need in the future a more general solution, which works with all non ascii characters and where I can use the `string-to-codepoints` function.

Comment: I have added an alternative approach using the `analyze-string` function to match on characters in a certain Unicode code block (e.g. Latin-1 Supplement in your case) and then to use the `'\''' || mf:int-to-hex(string-to-codepoints(.))` as the replacement for a match and the original substring in case of no match.